# How do I get to these RouteData?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Really struggling to get to these route data values...When I type I just cant seem to get into it only in debugger ! How do I get to them?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, `RouteData.Route` is shown to you as a `RouteBase` object, thus not giving you access to the defaults. You need to cast it to `Route`, the actual implementation:

```
((System.Web.Routing.Route)RouteData.Route).Defaults
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but what does this return?

```
RouteData.Route.Defaults["key"]; //Obviously replace "key" with the value you want
```